# Querying Youtube's title within a for loop shows only for first item

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, jcarousel

I've been trying to build a Youtube carousel based on [Michael Ouellette's carousel](http://www.michaelsouellette.com/projects/youtube_carousel/example.htm), which uses jCarousel

I need to fetch the titles of respective items in the carousel as well. I did some research and trying to fetch title using Youtube's JSON API. However, it's showing title for only first item - http://jsfiddle.net/inix/Cc8eC

My code:

```
    for (var num = 0, len = yt_videos.length; num < len; ++num) {
    yt_html = yt_html + "<li><a onclick='change_embeded(\"" + yt_videos[num] + "\")'><img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + yt_videos[num] + "/2.jpg' class='myimage' style='width:150px; height:100px;' /><br>";
    jQuery.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + yt_videos[num] + '?v=2&alt=jsonc', function (data, status, xhr) {
        document.getElementById("videotitle").innerHTML = (data.data.title);
    });
    yt_html = yt_html + '<span id="videotitle"></span></a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of your `<span id="videotitle"></span>`. You can't use the same id more than once by defintion. Try this:

```
for (var num = 0, len = yt_videos.length; num < len; ++num) {    
    yt_html = yt_html + "<li><a onclick='change_embeded(\"" + yt_videos[num] + "\")'><img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + yt_videos[num] + "/2.jpg' class='myimage' style='width:150px; height:100px;' /><br>";
    (function(i) {
        jQuery.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + yt_videos[i] + '?v=2&alt=jsonc', function (data, status, xhr) {
            document.getElementById("videotitle" + i).innerHTML = (data.data.title);
        });
    })(num);
    yt_html = yt_html + '<span id="videotitle' + num + '"></span></a></li>';
}
```

Comment: Coolio! Good to hear! ;)